# spring produces field of Controller annotation causes a GET 404

Tags: spring

In a GET request header:
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = "foo")
```

would return 200, while adding produces would return 404.

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = "foo", produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_UTF8_VALUE)
```

I have to use `produce` is because when called from a client like `curl`, if Accept header is not assigned as *application/json*, even though `ResponseEntity` specifies to use *application/json* by header, `AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor` would still have a 14-size `producibleMediaTypes`. However, if `produce` is used, it will have only 1 item, and thereafter calls the correct converter.

If produces is used:

[image: produces json AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor]

If produces is not used, but ResponseEntity has json in header (header in ResponseEntity does not affect `producibleMediaTypes`, **odd**)

[image: without produces]

using `produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE` log:

```
Mapped "{[/aa/foo],produces=[application/json]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity com.XXController.foo(int,int,java.lang.String)
```

Comment: What does it do with produces=MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON ?

Comment: @EugeneKuleshov   It causes `AbstractMessageConverterMethodProcessor` having json as `producibleMediaType`, and finally called the correct converter. Otherwise, the mediaType is `*/*` and it's compatible mediaType is "application/xml" and 5 others, finally returned pojo would be converted to xml. Now I am diverting this by adding json in curl header.

Comment: @EugeneKuleshov I attached 2 figures to show this difference.

Comment: Not answered my question. Can you check what happen when you set produced content type without encoding?

Comment: @EugeneKuleshov 404 too.